# I block ports using firewall still they are accessed

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall

I am using Avast firewall. I blocked ports from 1024 to 55535 yet I see apps established connection on ports in that range.

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot, the machine is making mirror connection.
Is this a malware or any kind of attach?

Regards,
Nealesh

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see these connections have source or target IP (or both) as `127.0.0.1`. This IP is `localhost` and what you see is internal communication between the processes of your machine. This is something which never leave your machine.

Comment: But if I have blocked the ports they should not be available. Secondly, I saw that web browsers stopped working saying firewall has blocked access. If the web browsers use 80 and 443, then why did this happen?

Comment: @Nealesh, have you check if you block `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: If I don't add ip address, it means all ip addressed right? I wrote rule assuming this.